# Postgresql: generate default volume value to integer rank

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the (fictional) table below to store messages in a discussion board, organised by topic, themselves identified by an integer:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGE(
  message_global_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  topic_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  message_nb_in_topic INTEGER,
  text TEXT
);
```

I want to set the column message_nb_in_topic to the equivalent of a sequence, but that resets for each topic number.

For example,

- I post for topic 0 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 0
- I post for topic 0 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 1
- I post for topic 1 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 0
- I post for topic 0 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 2
- I post for topic 1 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 1
- I post for topic 2 -> the message has message_nb_in_topic = 0

Is it possible to generate such sequence in postgresql ? I was thinking of some CREATE FUNCTION, but I am not very familiar with their usages.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Gordon's solution is the cleanest, however I forgot to mention I was behind some middleware that does not allow me to carry out any complex update.
Yet I ended up with the trigger bellow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_message_nb()
  RETURNS trigger AS '
  DECLARE
    max_for_topic int;
  BEGIN
    max_for_topic := (SELECT max(message_nb_in_topic) FROM MESSAGE WHERE topic_id=NEW.topic_id);
    IF max_for_topic IS NULL THEN
      NEW.message_nb_in_topic := 1;
    ELSE
      NEW.message_nb_in_topic := 1 + max_for_topic;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER add_messagenb_at_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON MESSAGE
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_message_nb();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your own function; `row_number()` does this for you:

```
select m.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by topic order by message_global_id) as seqnum
from messages m;
```

I missed that you want an `update`:

```
update messages m
    set message_nb_in_topic = mm.seqnum
    from (select m.*, 
                 row_number() over (partition by topic order by message_global_id) as seqnum
          from messages m
         ) mm
    where m.message_global_id = mm.message_global_id;
```

Comment: Sounds great ! Is it possible to make postgresql generate such number at insert time. I tried using a DEFAULT clause, but I get "ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in DEFAULT expressions".

Comment: @AntoineTrouve . . . You would have to use a trigger for that, alas, or perhaps a user-defined function.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Let me explore the documentation about triggers. Would you by chance have an idea on how it should look like in this case ?

Comment: @AntoineTrouve . . . I wouldn't advise writing a trigger for this under many circumstances.  You can get the information when you query the table.

Comment: In fact I am using Postgresql behind some middleware (and middle-server) that prevents me from using complex sql queries. Therefore I would be very glad to do it using some DB-side logic. What would you propose ?

Comment: I would propose a `created_at timestamp with time zone` field instead of message_nb_in_topic. It can be initialised without a trigger, and the message_nm_in_topic is in fact the function  `rank() OVER (partition by topic_id, ORDER BY created_at)` , thus redundant.